# Является ли пул потоков лучшим решением для многопоточного парсера?

Tags: java, многопоточность

**Контекст:**
Я так понимаю, что пул (ExecutorService) используется только когда нужно создать большое число потоков (по модели: поток родился, выполнил работу, умер) и тогда пул является ограничителем одновременно действующих, чтобы они всей своей массой не завалили нагрузкой доступные ресурсы машины (защита от чрезмерных потерь от переключения контекста). А вот, если я сразу создаю только ограниченное количество потоков (по числу ядер на машине) и потом "в ручную" отслеживаю их количество (если кто-то отвалился то вместо него генерирую новый), то в этом случае пул потоков и не требуется

**Преамбула**
Стоит задача парсить (40-100 тыс.) web-ссылок. Не знаю, как лучше поступить

Через пул код кажется проще(чище). Не нужно заводить счетчик работающих потоков, отслеживать не отвалился ли кто. Просто, в взять из коллекции ссылку, запустить парсер... и так в цикле 10ки тысяч раз. Пул сам потом отследит, чтобы одновременно работало не более указанного числа потоков.

Или все же, изначально создавать только несколько потоков, которые обрабатывают всю коллекцию ссылок. В этом случае потребуется немного больше кода.

**Вопрос**
Правильно ли я понимаю, что, если, чем проще код, тем надежнее/лучше/прибыльнее/красивее и т.п., то пул - это лучший выбор "ленивого-clean-кодера", или я что-то не учел с ним связанное?

Comment: Оба варианта плохи. Парсинг веб-ссылки предполагает IO-операции: скачать что-то с адреса. Поток в это время будет стоять. То есть он вообще не нужен. Скачивание следует делать асинхронно. А вот далее - собственно парсинг скачанного - уже можно делать в потоках.

Comment: Нет такого понятия как простой код, и это моё личное мнение.